# Why my cURL in PHP gets 403 Forbidden while cURL in shell gets 200?

Tags: php, curl

Code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://detail.1688.com/offer/543783250479.html?sk=consign");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$a = curl_exec($ch);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($data);
```

Result:

```
string(339) "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx/1.11.1
Date: Tue, 16 May 2017 03:46:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.11.1</center>
</body>
</html>
"
```

While I run `curl -I https://detail.1688.com/offer/543783250479.html?sk=consign` in my shell, it returns 200:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 May 2017 03:46:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=GBK
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0,s-maxage=0
b2c_auction: 543783250479
atp_isdpp: 99vb2b-2295161471
page_cache_info: {"is_new":true,"create_time":"2017-05-16T11:46:51","expire_time":3600000}
X-Cache: MISS TCP_REFRESH_MISS dirn:-2:-2
Via: aserver010103196008.et2[69,200-0,M]
url-hash: id=543783250479&detail.1688.com
Server: Tengine/Aserver
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
EagleEye-TraceId: 0b83e0c214949064118297808e926
```

Could anyone please give me some hints about why I get 403 by cURL in PHP?

Environment:

```
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with blackfire v1.10.6, https://blackfire.io, by Blackfireio Inc.
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it works normally,  try from a different ip address, you may have been banned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returning headers **without** using an `useragent`:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Tue, 16 May 2017 04:15:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 266
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://127.0.0.1/?sk=consign
X-Cache: MISS TCP_MISS dirn:-2:-2
Via: aserver010103196008.et2[0,302-0,M]
url-hash: id=543783250479&detail.1688.com
Server: Tengine/Aserver
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
EagleEye-TraceId: 0b83dc9c14949081466171756eb58d
```

The important part is:

```
Location: http://127.0.0.1/?sk=consign
```

if I use an `useragent`, I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 May 2017 04:17:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=GBK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0,s-maxage=0
b2c_auction: 543783250479
atp_isdpp: 99vb2b-2295161471
page_cache_info: {"is_new":true,"create_time":"2017-05-16T12:17:30","expire_time":3600000}
X-Cache: MISS TCP_MISS dirn:-2:-2
Via: aserver011128044194.eu13[106,200-0,M]
url-hash: id=543783250479&detail.1688.com
Server: Tengine/Aserver
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
EagleEye-TraceId: 0b802cd414949082503341644e23a0
```

Which is correct and it returns the desired `html`

---

Code used:

```
$url = "http://detail.1688.com/offer/543783250479.html?sk=consign";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0");
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

In curl `-I` stands for head request. Try setting the head request in your php as
:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```

And give it a try